# looking for a component which enables chatting in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking for a component like skype, icq, messenger or any other of that type, which I can integrate into my asp.net 3.0 / asp.net 3.5 web application, which enables chatting, sending messages, files etc. between the users of the web application. like GTalk one to one communication NOT chat room

Note that only users whose user details are stored in the database and are authenticated, are able to use the web application, and therefore the component.

Answer (score 2):

For authentication to you the application you can use any method of authentication that suits you the best and you can integrate messaging functionality using [Fluent.Net](http://fluentnet.codeplex.com/) and [MSN Sharp](http://code.google.com/p/msnp-sharp/)